# Django - Can I use one UpdateView to update fields on separate pages?

Tags: django, django-views, updateview

Let's say I have a Student model, with name and age fields, and I have a page with a DetailView class showing these fields. Let's say that rather than having one "update" button that will take me to a form to update all fields of my model at once, I want a separate button for each field that takes me to a separate page with a form to update it.

I know how I could do this with a separate HTML file and separate UpdateView class for each field, but it seems like there should be a cleaner way.

In the first HTML file I have two buttons:

```
<a href="{% url 'update_name' pk=student.pk%}">Update name</a>
<a href="{% url 'update_age' pk=student.pk%}">Update age</a>
```

In the second I have the form:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk', views.StudentDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    path('update_name/<int:pk>', views.StudentUpdateView.as_view(), name="update_name"),
    path('update_age/<int:pk>', views.StudentUpdateView.as_view(), name="update_age"),
]
```

Views:

```
class StudentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = models.Student
    template_name = 'update_student.html'
```

I suppose I'm looking for some sort of if statement that I can put in my view, like:

```
if condition:
    fields = ("name",)
elif condition2:
    fields = ("age",)
```

Hopefully this makes sense! Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to override the `fields` in your urls.py file.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk', views.StudentDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    path('update_name/<int:pk>', views.StudentUpdateView.as_view(fields=['name']), name="update_name"),
    path('update_age/<int:pk>', views.StudentUpdateView.as_view(fields=['age']), name="update_age"),
]
```

[`View.as_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) accepts keyword arguments, which are used to override the classes attributes for that occurrence.

Comment: Neat! Also needs saying, one can use the same html file for multiple forms. Either with just `{{form.as_p}}` or by surrounding each explicitly rendered input field with `{% if "fieldname" in form.fields %}`